# How to automatically fetch JSON object in Background

Tags: android, json

How can i make my APP run in background always and  Automatically fetch updated JSON api data?
I am beginner in android studio and working on APP which need to monitor the changes in JSON data and generate action accordingly. I learned how to interface JSON API with VOLLEY library and able to read the JSON objects. 
e.g. Instagram, Facebook works in background and give notification.

Comment: This is a perfect use case of a work manager. Check out the official documentation
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try it with work manager.